# Print all possible combinations of size r, from an array of size n

Tags: java, recursion, interview-questions, combinatorics

This is my working solution for the following problem: given an array of integers of size *n*, print all possible combinations of size *r*.

Before I proceed to the solution, I have the following question: combination means that the order does not matter, right? I.e. printing `{1, 2}` is the same as `{2, 1}`, so I want to avoid repetitions?

If yes, here is what I do to avoid printing duplicate combinations: presort the given array `arr`, and if for some `i` I have that `arr[i] == arr[i+1]` I just skip this iteration.

Is my approach correct? Is there better solution?

```
package recursion;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Combinations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5};
        int r = 3;
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        combine(arr, r);
    }

    private static void combine(int[] arr, int r) {
        int[] res = new int[r];
        doCombine(arr, res, 0, 0, r);
    }



    private static void doCombine(int[] arr, int[] res, int currIndex, int level, int r) {
        if(level == r){
            printArray(res);
            return;
        }
        for (int i = currIndex; i < arr.length; i++) {
            res[level] = arr[i];
            doCombine(arr, res, i+1, level+1, r);
            //way to avoid printing duplicates
            if(i < arr.length-1 && arr[i] == arr[i+1]){
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printArray(int[] res) {
        for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(res[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Combinations = Order does *not* matter. Permutations = Order **does** matter.

Comment: this approach is correct. however i wonder if there is a more efficient method to do this.

Comment: @LZH I solved many such problems after this post, and all af them have the same framework, i.e. for loop and in the for loop is the recursive statement. If you find something better, please tell me.

Comment: i was solving a problem with a slight variation, but this frameworks works for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think that by avoiding duplicates, you are essentially changing the definition of the question at hand.

If that is indeed the definition of question, then instead of sorting the array and avoiding duplicates, you can simply get rid of the duplicates to begin with by using a set instead of an array:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int i : arr)
    set.add(i);
```

---

In addition, for better modularity, I think that you should separate the algorithm itself from the printing:

- Create an empty `List<List<Integer>>` instance
- Pass it to the `doCombine` method, to fill it in with all combinations
- Print it in the `main` method (the `combine` method looks kind of redundant)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! The definition wasn't clear for me also. I took the question from here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/ and here they do the same - avoid duplicates, although I'm not sure if we have to do this. I tried to find more formal definition of the question, but I couldn't.

Comment: You're welcome. The solution I gave above should help you get rid of the duplicate **input** values "more nicely" than the way that you are doing it now. If the duplicate input values should **not** be removed (and a combination like `3,4,4` for example is allowed), then you will have the problem of duplicate **output** values. In order to solve that problem, you can use the second suggestion that I made above, but use `HashMap<String,List<Integer>>` instead of `List<List<Integer>>`. You will also have to keep the `Arrays.sort(arr)` in this case.

Comment: Combinations = Order does *not* matter. Permutations = Order **does** matter. So avoiding duplicates should be done.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Yes, duplicate **results** should be avoided (`(1,2)` shouldn't be in the result if `(2,1)` already is). But duplicate **elements** are (generally) allowed (depending on the question). So `(2,3,3)` should be in the result if the input is `[2,3,3]`. And that is exactly what the code of OP does.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: Well then, as I mentioned in the answer, I think that it is "more appropriate" to use a `Set`, thus remove duplicate values.